# Convert YUV420 to RGBA in webgl

Tags: javascript, rendering, webgl, rgb, yuv

I am looking for a simple Javascript function that can take a YUV420 data array, convert it to RGBA using WebGL and return back the RGBA array. I have been looking into different javascript libraries, but there is very tight coupling with H264 decoding and images etc, such as Broadway.js and o3d.js.

If there could be a generic function such as this:

```
function yuv2rgb(yuv420DataArray){
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //convert yuv420DataArray to rgbaDataArray using WebGL
    //...
    //...
    //...
    return rgbaDataArray;
}
```

that would be a great help!

(Once I have the RGBA data array in I would render it on the canvas like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043144/javascript-webgl-rgba-array-to-screen))

Comment: The [english wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) provides everything you need.